# How to pass a Json Array from JSP to Servlet using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page in which I am sending an AJAX Request to servlet having data as JSON Array. But I am getting null value in the servlet. Request.getParameter() returns null, but when i tried using a simple json object for e.g. data:{jsonData:'test'} it works for me.

Ajax Snippet

```
function updateStatus() {       

    var Url = {

            "Urls" : [

            {
                "Env" : "DEV : CC",
                "Url" : "https://localhost:8081/cc",
                "Status" : "Up",
                "Revision" : ""             
            }, {
                "Env" : "MO : CM",
                "Url" : "https://localhost:8082/ab",
                "Status" : "Up",
                "Revision" : ""             } ]         }


          $.ajax({
             url:'Environment',
             data:{jsonData : Url},
             type:'post',
             cache:false,
             success:function(data){
                alert('Hi');
             },
             error:function(){
               alert('error');
             }
          });

    }
```

Servlet function

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try 
        {
            String jsonString = request.getParameter("jsonData");
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
              String path = array.getString(i);
              System.out.println(path);
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you try to call JSON.stringify() on the object you're posting? (data: JSON.stringify( Url )). Also, in your Servlet, you're looking for an array in "jsonString", but "jsonString" is at best an object, containing the array "Urls".

Comment: Hi Heiko, I tried but didn't work $.ajax({
            url:'Environment',
            data:JSON.stringify(Url),
            contentType: 'charset=UTF-8' ,
            type:'post',
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
               alert('Hi');
            },
            error:function(){
              alert('error');
            }
         });

Comment: Also i changed the servlet code   String jsonString = request.getParameter("jsonData");
   String[] jsonString1 = request.getParameterValues("jsonData");

Comment: I guess jquery does the JSON.stringify automatically anyway, it was probably not a brilliant idea. 
In your Servlet, try JSONObject object = new JSONObject( jsonString ); JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("Urls");

Comment: Hi Heiko, By the way this jsonString is itself null, if i pass it to JSONObject variable it will give me a null pointer exception.

Comment: Try `data:{jsonData : JSON.stringify(Url)}` instead of  `data:JSON.stringify(Url)` .

Comment: data:{'jsonData':JSON.stringify(Url)} use quotes for key since its a key

Comment: If the server is not responsible to process parameters from the request then you probably   have inconsistent services involved error which prevents you from getting further processing the data like validation. Nevertheless you just fail on the wrong request itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send your data, If you check the `Form Data` of resource `Environment`  on a browser developer tool "Network" tab (in Chrome), you will notice that your data is being sent to server as array as follows:

```
jsonData[Urls][0][Env]:DEV : CC
jsonData[Urls][0][Url]:https://localhost:8081/cc
jsonData[Urls][0][Status]:Up
jsonData[Urls][0][Revision]:
jsonData[Urls][1][Env]:MO : CM
jsonData[Urls][1][Url]:https://localhost:8082/ab
jsonData[Urls][1][Status]:Up
jsonData[Urls][1][Revision]:
```

So, in this case, you can access each of them severally:

```
request.getParameter("jsonData[Urls][0][Url]");
request.getParameter("jsonData[Urls][1][Env]");
```

---

But you can use `data:{jsonData : JSON.stringify(Url)}` and get it by `request.getParameter("jsonData");` to send valid Json string to the server side and parse it using any Json parser libs.

**Note:** Your json data is encoded as key-value pairs of content type: "**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**" not as "application/json". Therefore you can access it by `request.getParameter()`.

Comment: It worked for me thanks alot ! There was a another culprit, i used contentType: 'application/json'. Can you give me a small hint why it is not getting read. or how can i access it.